# Create Entities from existing DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

Newest Version Symfony2 and using MAMP on a MAC. Following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

My Error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                    
  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.
```

Don't have any idea. What is wrong?

A connection to my db is working. Because I tried to create a table and the output was that the table exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I missed it and here is the solution of my question.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types-in-the-schematool